# What does : TypeError: cannot concatenate 'str' and 'list' objects mean?

Tags: python, string

What does this error mean?

> TypeError: cannot concatenate 'str' and 'list' objects

Here's part of the code:

```
for j in ('90.','52.62263.','26.5651.','10.8123.'):
    if j == '90.':
        z = ('0.')
    elif j == '52.62263.':
        z = ('0.', '72.', '144.', '216.', '288.')

    for k in z:
        exepath = os.path.join(exe file location here)
        exepath = '"' + os.path.normpath(exepath) + '"'
        cmd = [exepath + '-j' + str(j) + '-n' + str(z)]

        process=Popen('echo ' + cmd, shell=True, stderr=STDOUT )
        print process
```

Comment: Can you post your code?

Comment: got it- my answer works for you now.

Comment: else == '52.62263.': <-- is a syntax error in python

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I'm not sure you're aware that `cmd` is a one-element `list`, and not a string.

Changing that line to the below would construct a string, and the rest of your code will work:

```
# Just removing the square brackets
cmd = exepath + '-j' + str(j) + '-n' + str(z)
```

I assume you used brackets just to group the operations. That's not necessary if everything is on one line. If you wanted to break it up over two lines, you should use parentheses, not brackets:

```
# This returns a one-element list
cmd = [exepath + '-j' + str(j) + 
       '-n' + str(z)]

# This returns a string
cmd = (exepath + '-j' + str(j) + 
       '-n' + str(z))
```

Anything between square brackets in python is *always* a `list`. Expressions between parentheses are evaluated as normal, unless there is a comma in the expression, in which case the parentheses act as a `tuple` constructor:

```
# This is a string
str = ("I'm a string")

# This is a tuple
tup = ("I'm a string","me too")

# This is also a (one-element) tuple
tup = ("I'm a string",)
```

Comment: @Tyler - not sure what you're talking about. My code contains no loops.

Comment: referring to his. seems to almost randomly loop back to 90 when it shouldn't.

Answer (score 4):

string objects can only be concatenated with other strings.  Python is a strongly-typed language.  It will not coerce types for you.

you can do:

```
'a' + '1'
```

but not:

```
'a' + 1
```

in your case, you are trying to concat a string and a list.  this won't work.  you can append the item to the list though, if that is your desired result:

```
my_list.append('a')
```

Answer (score 2):

There is ANOTHER problem in the OP's code:

`z = ('0.')` then later `for k in z:`

The parentheses in the first statement will be ignored, leading to the second statement binding `k` first to `'0'` and then `'.'` ... looks like `z = ('0.', )` was intended.