# python，typeerror：cannot concatenate 'str 'and 'float' objects

Tags: python

```
import easygui

fahrenheit = easygui.integerbox("Please input fahrenheit: ")

celsius = (fahrenheit -32) *5.0 / 9

easygui.msgbox("celsius is :" + celsius )
```

Comment: Did you look this up? This gets asked like at least a few times a day.

Comment: `easygui.msgbox("celsius is :" + str(celsius))`

Comment: because you can't concat floats and strings maybe can't tell

Comment: @Ev.Kounis think you

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What does : TypeError: cannot concatenate 'str' and 'list' objects mean?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1014503/what-does-typeerror-cannot-concatenate-str-and-list-objects-mean) (same concept)

Comment: @Carcigenicate sorry,this's my first time use stackoverflow ,I'll look for a similar problem next time. think you

Comment: @jo.ma Whenever you get an error, just Google the error. That will almost always solve your problem.

Comment: @L_Church think you

Comment: @Carcigenicate yes

Comment: @L_Church that question is about `list` not `float`, and it's not as clear as this one. Maybe there's a better dupe out there?

Comment: @Carcigenicate is there another language where this actually works, or is it just a newbie misunderstanding?

Comment: @MarkRansom Are you asking if there's a language that allows implicit conversions to Strings?

Comment: @Carcigenicate yes that's exactly what I'm asking. I thought there was at least one, but I've never used it so I can't remember.

Comment: @MarkRansom Yes. Java does for example, as do all the languages that I know that compile to JVM byte code (Clojure, Scala...). Python just doesn't because it's quite strongly typed.

Comment: @MarkRansom Wait, I'm pretty sure Java does. Been awhile since I've written it. And Clojure does since it's dynamically typed, and almost all string operations call `str` on their argument at some point. Not the same thing, but Clojure's `join` works on vectors of characters for example.

Comment: there probably is but that IS the same concept and gives the related answer it doesn't matter what typing is

Comment: @MarkRansom You might be thinking of PHP. I seem to recall it playing fast and loose with conversions.

Comment: Think you all the seniors engineers friends to answer,correct the error,China is now late at night,I'm going to sheep,think you very much .my English is not good so use google translate.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to convert the calculated number into a string before performing string methods on it. This might help:

```
("Celcius is:" + str(celcius))
```

You could also use the following method if you do not want to convert float to string:

```
("Celcius is: {}".format(celcius))
```